# How to extract values from HTML <input type=“date”> using jQuery to a specific website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

can you help me out with this problem? What i want is to transfer the value the date of "checkin" and "checkout" to a specific URL. But it doesn't work with my codes.

```js
$('#submitBooking').on('click', function() {

  var checkin = new Date($('#checkinbooking').val());
  inDay = checkin.getDate();
  inMonth = checkin.getMonth() + 1;
  inYear = checkin.getFullYear();
  checkin = ([inYear, inMonth, inDay].join('-'));

  var checkout = new Date($('#checkoutbooking').val());
  outDay = checkout.getDate();
  outMonth = checkout.getMonth() + 1;
  outYear = checkout.getFullYear();
  checkout = ([outYear, outMonth, outDay].join('-'));

  window.location.href =
    'https://hotels.cloudbeds.com/reservation/oL7RdR?checkin=' + checkin + '&checkout=' + checkout;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="https://hotels.cloudbeds.com/reservation/oL7RdR#/post" method="post">
  <label for="checkin" class="VP"><span class="VC">From</span></label>
  <input type="date" name="checkin" id="checkinbooking">

  <label for="checkout" class="VP"><span class="VC">To</span></label>
  <input type="date" name="checkout" id="checkoutbooking">

  <input type="submit" value="Check Availability" id="submitBooking">
</form>
```

Comment: Not working means? What happens exactly?

Comment: Please be a little more specific. What is not working according to your expectation? It seems you have some conflicting methods. Your form action will post to the url then you are trying to set the window location within your event listener. You should change your event listener to listen for the `submit` event on the form. If you are intending to `GET` the url you are constructing for the change in `window.location`, you need to `preventDefault()` on the event so that `action` is never called as a `POST`

Comment: Willing to help. But unclear of the problem you are facing? Can you get the date ? is it not opening the url ?

Comment: I try to change the code with this.

Comment: After clicking the button, i am being directed to this link https://hotels.cloudbeds.com/reservation/oL7RdR?checkin=2018-07-12&checkout=2018-07-14#checkin=2018-07-11&checkout=2018-07-12 insted of https://hotels.cloudbeds.com/reservation/oL7RdR#checkin=2018-07-12&checkout=2018-07-14

Comment: meaning, the date I input was not able to received by the <input type='date'> on the link I want to go.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully work with it. What I did is change the method to `get` and used the `preventDefault()` and some changes in my `href`

```js
$('#submitBooking').on('click', 
function(event){
    event.preventDefault()

    var checkin = new Date($('#checkinbooking').val());
    inDay = checkin.getDate();
    inMonth = checkin.getMonth()+1;
    inYear = checkin.getFullYear();
    checkin = ([inYear, inMonth, inDay].join('-'));

    var checkout = new Date($('#checkoutbooking').val());
    outDay = checkout.getDate();
    outMonth = checkout.getMonth()+1;
    outYear = checkout.getFullYear();
    checkout = ([outYear, outMonth, outDay].join('-'));

    window.location.href = 'https://hotels.cloudbeds.com/reservation/oL7RdR#checkin='+checkin+'&checkout='+checkout;
});
```

```html
<form action="https://hotels.cloudbeds.com/reservation/oL7RdR#" method="get">
      <label for="checkin" class="VP"><span class="VC">From</span></label>
      <input type="date" name="checkin" id="checkinbooking">

      <label for="checkout" class="VP"><span class="VC">To</span></label>
      <input type="date" name="checkout" id="checkoutbooking">

      <input type="submit" value="Check Availability" id="submitBooking">
     </form>
```

Comment: Why do you need a `form` and `preventDefault` action and update the `location` ?